# Powershell could not create ssl/tls secure channel, OS supported ciphers not used

Tags: ssl

I am trying to use powershell to connect to a dns service desec.io from a Windows server 2012 R2 server but the connection is failing with the error The request was aborted could not create ssl/tls secure channel. I used wireshark to inspect the hello packet to make sure a TLS 1.2 connection was being used and to look at the list of ciphers that are sent. My server is sending this list of ciphers when attempting to connect:

```
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
```

I used ssllabs to inspect the website and determine what ciphers it wants to use. This is the list of ciphers the website will accept:

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 2048 bits   FS  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)   ECDH secp521r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS 256
```

Looking at the above cipher lists it is obvious why the connection fails since there is no matching cipher between client/server. My question is that according to this Microsoft page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1
The ciphers TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 are supported on Windows server 2012 R2 and should be enabled by default. I even used the IISCrypto tool to verify that these ciphers are listed and set to enabled. So why would powershell not send these ciphers?
FYI: I don't think powershell itself is relevant here because I get a similar error and failed connection if I try to visit this site from Internet Explorer.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `wmic qfe get hotfixid,installedon` ?

Comment: Output is too long for a comment. Here are the more recent entries in the list: `KB5008883  3/9/2022
KB5009624  3/9/2022
KB5010419  3/9/2022
KB5010462  3/9/2022
KB5011564  3/9/2022
KB5012124  4/14/2022
KB5012170  8/10/2022
KB5012670  4/14/2022
KB5012672  4/14/2022
KB5013631  5/12/2022
KB5014025  5/12/2022
KB5014633  6/16/2022
KB5016264  7/13/2022
KB5016370  8/10/2022
KB5017038  9/15/2022
KB5017398  9/15/2022
KB5018519  10/12/2022
KB5018922  10/12/2022
KB5020620  11/9/2022
KB5020878  12/15/2022
KB5021294  12/15/2022`

Comment: Here is a paste bin link to the full output: https://paste-bin.xyz/971767

Comment: @GregAskew I meant to mention you in the previous comment. Not sure if it is necessary.

Comment: @GregAskew Anything interesting in the output you requested?